# Naming conflict with the Swift StreamVideo SDK

Tags: ios, swift, macos, getstream-io, swift-package

How can I solve a naming conflict between e.g. a local `User` object and the same object name in the StreamVideo SDK?

Regular imports can lead to problems with existing project files that have the same names. Also, there can be a conflict with the `StreamVideo` class as it's the same name as the package itself.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `typealias` in a separate file with the custom name (in this case `StreamUser`) that you want to give the object:

```swift
import struct StreamVideo.User

typealias StreamUser = StreamVideo.User
```

This works for all other naming conflicts that might occur as well.